# <%= render @products %> specify specific folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I noticed that for this code to work (where @products as an array of product objects), I need a products folder and a _products.rb file.  How can I specify a different folder and file name for example, instead of app/views/products/_products.rb, I have app/views/invoice/_Prod_view1.rb?

```
<%= render @products %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `Product` model write this:

```
def to_partial_path
  'invoice/_prod_view1'
end
```

Read documentation of [`to_partial_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Conversion.html#method-i-to_partial_path).

Instead of explicitly naming the location of a partial, you can also let `PartialRenderer` do the work and pick the proper path by checking [`to_partial_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) method.

Comment: Is there a way to define multiple partials for different views??

Comment: @user2012677 Based on which conditions ? Do you have any attribute in the product record, based on which you want to decide where it should go ?

Comment: I'll be using different partials for the model in different templates and layouts, so based on the view.

Comment: @user2012677 No then there is no automatic way, you have do it manually.. Another hack is there, which doesn't look better than manually. The idea id too keep attar_accessor inside the model, and switch its value when rendering, and then use conditional check inside the above method I gave in the answer, and return the partial string. Does it look good? it is unto you.. :)

Comment: @user2012677 read this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html to see how can you do it manually ? Please open the link.. read *Rendering a collection of partials* section